# Formatting Date And Time In Flutter During Return Type

Tags: datetime, flutter, format, datetime-format, return-type

I have created fun: **HomeScreen()** which extends to **HomeScreenState().**
I have used HomeScreenState() to return Timing And Date.
But the issue is I'm unable to format time for **HH:MM (am or pm)** and date to **DD/MM/YYYY.**

```
_currentTime(){
  return "${DateTime.now().hour} : ${DateTime.now().minute}";
 }
 _currentDate(){
  return "${DateTime.now().day}.${DateTime.now().month}.${DateTime.now().year}";
 }
```

I want this to be in required format.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please share more of your code and give an example of the output you want to see? While you're at it, take a look a the guidelines on how to ask a good question, which will help you get better answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: When you click ask a question on any SO site, there are a list of things (on the right) to be included to make sure the question is correct for that particular site. This site requires one to include specific code and errors. 
Copy the entire dart file here so we can eval and give a better answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this package called 'intl' for the purpose of formatting

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Fing the detailed documentation [here](https://pub.dev/packages/intl).